# Is JFrog Back Up in case of data loss

Tags: artifactory

Please can someone advise?

Our business is new to JFrog and i would like to know if JFrog automatically backs up the data. Or is this something that we need to set up at a further cost/package?

many thanks

Comment: This sounds like a question to the customer support of JFrog.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which JFrog application. If you mean Artifactory - then yes. you can setup automatic backup directly in application ->
https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-for-artifactory-backups-and-disaster-recovery/

Backup by application is available only for small instances - less than 1TB data or less than 1 milion of objects.
If you have bigger instance then database and filestore must be backed up separately using standalone database/linux/cloud tools. Still something to can be easily automated.

All this you can find in their "documentation".
The biggest problem in my opinion is that with bigger Artifactory instances it is virtually not possible to do backup/restore at repository level. If you have 20TB you must backup/restore everything at once.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information, i have had a look into to what you have mentioned and it seems that we will exceed 1TB data very soon so we will need to focus on using the stand alone method.